# Python Docx Module Is Not Inside The Site-Packages Folder

Tags: python, module

I am new to python and I am trying to install the docx module, however it does not appear inside the site-packages folder.
First, I thought it was not showing up because my pycharm was outdated. Updated the base interpreter from 3.9 to 3.10 as well as pycharm. Deleted the **venv** folder and all that jazz. Opened the windows cmd and wrote `pip install python--docx` It shows that it is already installed:

**Requirement already satisfied: python--docx in c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (0.8.11)**

**Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=2.3.2 in c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from python--docx) (4.8.0)**

But is nowhere to be found in the site-packages folder in either version of Python, what should I do?

Comment: did you try running `which pip` to make sure you are looking through the correct directory?  You could also try starting a new virtualenv outside of pycharm and see if it install correctly externally.

Comment: Dont worry @alexpdev, I fixed it! It was simple, just had the check the box _inherit global site packages_ when changing the base interpreter in Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

My site-packages folder in Pycharm showed that they were disabled, colored orange, but it turns out that I just had to delete everthing inside the **venv** folder again and just check the box inherit global site-packages when changing the base interpreter. Everthing is fixed now!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like python-docx doesn't work anymore. It throws a legacy error and appears to be out of date ver. 0.8.11. When you google - seems like there is a newer version https://pypi.org/project/docx/